# Centering Text over Image using Foundation

Tags: image, text, overlay, center

So I'm trying to do what seems to be a very simple thing, yet I can't seem to get it to work...Center some text over an image. I want the image to scale the entire width of the screen, with no white space on either side, and scale height to let's say like 30% of the screen, and then put the text right in the center of the image.

I created this to show my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/sq9we118/

I've tried:

```
text-align: center;
```

^^ which does nothing.

Also:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

^^which moves the text over 50%, but does not move it down at all.

I've tried more than this, I just can't remember exactly what I did. I've tried multiple 'div' setups with the image and text in the same div, separate divs, only the text in a separate div, as well as various CSS settings that I found as answers on this site for others with a similar problem, but none have worked for me.

I'm using Foundation, if that makes any difference. I tried it without Foundation, and I couldn't even get the image to scale 100% the width of the screen without the left and right white space.

Also also, as you can see, I have:

```
width: 100%;
height: 15em;
```

for the image. If I change the height to any %, the image disappears. I can do pixels for both, but I want the image to scale for screen sizing.

I'm new to web development, so this is all pretty demoralizing, since I can't even get these two simple problems solved, lol. Thanks guys(and gals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS-Tricks site has [a fantastic guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) on how to center with CSS that should be able to help you in the future. I've created [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8c4sb0o/) with a possible solution to your problem; I've pasted the CSS below.

```
.image {
    position: relative;
}

img.big_image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15em;
}

div.overlay_text {
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 48px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephanie! I finally figured it out by looking at the code of other websites, but that guide is helpful.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!